# How is JMS different from Reactive Streams?

Tags: jms, reactive-programming

I am learning about Reactive Streams in API and I am struck by the similarity between this and JMS. In JMS too we have asynchronous processing, publishers and subscribers. What perspective am I missing in making this equivalence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for a stream to be reactive, it should be able to apply **back pressure**. (See [this initiative](http://www.reactive-streams.org/).)

JMS does not support that. The topic publisher or queue sender is never notified of downstream obstructions and hence will not be able to react appropriately.

Answer (score 5):

Reactive Streams is back pressure oriented, JMS is message oriented. Although you could do back pressure using JMS.

Blocking API (non-reactive)

`java.util.concurrent.Future::get` <-> `javax.jms.MessageConsumer.receive`

Non-blocking API

`org.reactivestreams.Publisher::subscribe` <-> `javax.jms.MessageConsumer::setMessageListener`
`org.reactivestreams.Subscriber::onNext` <-> `javax.jms.MessageListener::onMessage`

Back pressure API <-> Message API

`org.reactivestreams.Subscription::request` <-> `javax.jms.MessageProducer::send`

Initialization / finalization / error-handling

`org.reactivestreams.Subscriber::onSubscribe` <-> `javax.jms.MessageListener::onMessage`
`org.reactivestreams.Subscriber::onError` <-> `javax.jms.MessageListener::onMessage`
`org.reactivestreams.Subscriber::onComplete` <-> `javax.jms.MessageListener::onMessage`
`org.reactivestreams.Subscription::cancel` <-> `javax.jms.MessageProducer::send`